# Netlogo procedure - return function

Tags: netlogo

The error is

> There is already a procedure called FORAGING_EFFORT

Is there another return function in Netlogo or any other solution?

```
 to-report fp [foraging_effort]
      report (5 / (1 + exp (2 - foraging_effort * 2)))
    end

to-report foraging_effort [forage_min forage_rate energy_level]
  ifelse energy_level <= forage_min
    [ report 0 ]
    [ report (forage_rate * (energy_level - forage_min)) ]
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in NetLogo shares a single namespace. It means that a variable cannot have the same name as a procedure, and vice versa.

In your case, the `fp` reporter has an argument named `foraging_effort`, but you also have a reporter called `foraging_effort`. This is what NetLogo is complaining about.

Normally, I would say: "Simply rename one of the two, and you should be good to go," but the way you phrased your question makes me suspect there might be something else going on. Is it possible that you wanted to call the `foraging_effort` reporter from within your `fp` reporter? In that case, you probably don't need the argument to the reporter, and you should remove the `[foraging_effort]` part after `to-report fp`.